# PHP 5.3 changelog?

Tags: php, changelog

Can anyone point me a good(with examples) changelog for php 5.3?
I'm hearing lot's of ppl doing code migration to it and I'm wondering what is so new about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The PHP 5.3 Migration Guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php) is a good place to start.

Comment: Seems interesting, still wondering if there is a short tutorial on it. Thanks.

Comment: In the shared web hosting of my website, I just changed the PHP version settings and I transformed my account's PHP from 5.2.x to 5.3.x and I noticed a break through in performance. Does that true, or it is a fake notice?!!