# What's the difference between PHP 5.3.x and PHP 5.2.x and which one should I use?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP 5.3 changelog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442066/php-5-3-changelog)

I am new to PHP, and I am confused which PHP version I should use: 5.3.3 (latest in 5.3.x), or 5.2.14 (latest in 5.2.x). What's the difference between them?

Comment: You all completely misunderstood the question. I was not asking for a changelog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read about some of the PHP 5.3 features here:

http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php

You might as well go with the latest release if you have a choice.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to read the [5.3 Migration Guide](http://us.php.net/migration53), which outlines in detail the differences between 5.2 and 5.3.